# Obtaining inverse relationships from a generic List in Realm

Tags: ios, realm

I would like to create a generic Realm List consisting of different class types (but all of superclass `Object`).

```
class Parent: Object {    
    var children = List<Object>()
}

class Child1: Object {
 let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "children")
}

class Child2: Object {
 let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "children")
}
```

Linking instances of `Child1` and `Child2` to a `Parent` object works fine, however, the inverse relationships gives the following error:

```
- Property ‘Parent.children’ declared as origin of linking objects property ‘Child1.parents’ links to a different class.
- Target type 'RealmSwiftObject' doesn't exist for property ‘children’.
```

How could it be ensured that the `parents` property is determined correctly? I can imagine that it should be filtered for the class type where it belongs to (i.e. `Child1` or `Child2`) but I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a workaround I am not aware of, it is not possible to store different types in a `List`.

`List`s contain other `Object`s of a single type and have an interface very similar to a mutable `Array`. (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships)

Comment: That's correct. Realm generally doesn't support type polymorphism. See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance for details and workarounds.

Comment: I overlooked this in the documentation, but I will try to find a work around.